# How to dynamically change OpenSearch/ElasticSearch Apache HttpClient5 properties with new Java client?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-httpclient-4.x, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am using [opensearch-java](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java/) client to connect to my OpenSearch cluster hosted in AWS. The client uses Apache HttpClient5 Transport to connect to the cluster. This is how my client is setup:

```
protected OpenSearchAsyncClient createInstance() throws Exception {
        final HttpHost[] hosts = config.getNodeAddresses().stream().map(
            address -> new HttpHost("https", address, config.getPort())).toArray(HttpHost[]::new);

        final BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .build();

        final ApacheHttpClient5TransportBuilder builder = ApacheHttpClient5TransportBuilder.builder(hosts);
        builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> {
            final TlsStrategy tlsStrategy = ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
                        .setSslContext(sslcontext)
                        .build();

            final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder
                    .create()
                    .setTlsStrategy(tlsStrategy)
                    .setPoolConcurrencyPolicy(PoolConcurrencyPolicy.STRICT)
                    .setMaxConnTotal(config.getMaxConnTotal())
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(config.getMaxConnPerRoute())
                    .setConnectionTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofSeconds(config.getConnectionTimeToLive()))
                    .setValidateAfterInactivity(TimeValue.ofSeconds(
                            config.getValidateAfterInactivity()))
                    .setConnPoolPolicy(PoolReusePolicy.FIFO)
                    .build();

            return httpClientBuilder
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .evictIdleConnections(TimeValue.ofSeconds(config.getEvictIdleConnections()))
                    .evictExpiredConnections()
                    .setIOReactorConfig(
                            IOReactorConfig.custom()
                                    .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(config.getSoTimeout()))
                                    .setSoKeepAlive(true)
                                    .setIoThreadCount(config.getIoThreadCount())
                                    .setSelectInterval(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(config.getIOSelectInterval()))
                                    .build())
                    .setIoReactorExceptionCallback(e ->
                            LOGGER.error("OpenSearch client's IOReactor encountered uncaught exception", e));
        });

        builder.setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(config.getConnectionRequestTimeout()))
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(config.getConnectTimeout()))
                .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(config.getReadTimeout()))
                .setConnectionKeepAlive(TimeValue.ofSeconds(config.getConnectionKeepAlive())));
        builder.setFailureListener(new ApacheHttpClient5Transport.FailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Node node) {
                LOGGER.error("OpenSearch client encountered failure in this node: {}", node.getHost());
            }
        });
        builder.setMapper(new JacksonJsonpMapper(Mapper.getObjectMapper()));

        final OpenSearchTransport transport = builder.build();
        return new OpenSearchAsyncClient(transport);
}
```

Here's the version of OpenSearch I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.core5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore5</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to change the client's properties dynamically during runtime, instead of changing the properties and restarting all the nodes. But, the client doesn't have any accessible methods that I can use to change the properties dynamically. Is there a way to change these properties dynamically by changing config.? Thank you!

Comment: which properties do you refer to?

Comment: In the client setup I posted, anything that is using config.<properties>, for e.g. config.getNodeAddresses().